# getting opposite data from Api using Go

Tags: go

Here I am getting closing data from Api but I am getting opposite data. expecting (2021-05-07 1931.3 ) but getting ( 2005-08-17 534.169 ) so why I am getting opposite data and how can I solve this problem , help

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Data struct {
    MetaData        MetaData               `json:"Meta Data"`
    TimeSeriesDaily map[string]DataElement `json:"Time Series (Daily)"`
}
type MetaData struct {
    OneInformation     string `json:"1. Information"`
    TwoSymbol          string `json:"2. Symbol"`
    ThreeLastRefreshed string `json:"3. Last Refreshed"`
    FiveOutputSize     string `json:"5. Output Size"`
    SixTimeZone        string `json:"6. Time Zone"`
}

type DataElement struct {
    OneOpen    string `json:"1. open"`
    TwoHigh    string `json:"2. high"`
    ThreeLow   string `json:"3. low"`
    FourClose  string `json:"4. close"`
    FiveVolume string `json:"5. volume"`
}

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=RELIANCE.BSE&outputsize=full&apikey=BV68V9VC5MTQFJRT")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var y Data
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &y)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(y)
    var l string
    var lop string
    for k, data := range y.TimeSeriesDaily {
        _, lop, l = ("%s closed at %s\n"), (k), (data.FourClose)
    }
    fmt.Println(lop, l)
}
```

screenshot of data - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI7kl.png)

Comment: Maps in Go are not ordered. So your `for ... range` is iterating over the map in an unspecified order. In each iteration you overwrite the `l` and `lop` variables, meaning that at the end of the loop `l` and `lop` will hold the values from the last iteration. You then print those last-iteration variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are unmarshalling `TimeSeriesDaily` into a map and maps are unordered, just like JSON objects.
So, each time you loop over `TimeSeriesDaily` you will get a different value.

You can solve this by the following code,

```
    timeSeries := make([]map[string]DataElement, 0)

    for date, data := range y.TimeSeriesDaily {
        timeSeries = append(timeSeries, map[string]DataElement{date: data})
    }

    sort.Slice(timeSeries, func(i, j int) bool {
        layout := "2006-01-02"

        var date1 time.Time
        for k := range timeSeries[i] {
            date1, err = time.Parse(layout, k)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
        }

        var date2 time.Time
        for k := range timeSeries[j] {
            date2, err = time.Parse(layout, k)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

        }

        return date1.Before(date2)
    })

    for k, v := range timeSeries[len(timeSeries)-1] {
        fmt.Println("Closing Date: " + k)
        fmt.Println("Closing Price: " + v.FourClose)
    }
```

Output:

```
Closing Date: 2021-05-07
Closing Price: 1931.3
```

**repl.it link**: https://replit.com/@RamarajaRamanuj/SortTimeSlice
Will be slow to see output as it will take time for repl.it to startup.

Here, you are looping through the map, storing the entries in a slice, sorting the slice by ascending order of date.

Now the `timeSeries` slice is ordered by the oldest date as the first element and the latest date as the last element. You can simply pick the last element to know the latest closing price.